# Comparing Two Kernel Density Estimates

Tags: distributions, statistical-significance, density-function, density-estimation

I developing a kernel density estimate in Java for a control and test sample population given a certain treatment of the data. I am wondering the best way to test the similarity of the distributions to obtain a p-value corresponding to whether the treatment had a significant effect on the control population.

I have researched this and I know I can do a K-S test, but that requires me to get a CDF from the density estimate before running the test. I've also found multiple sources that talk about finding the integrated square error of the two distributions, but I can't find a best practice on how to do this (frequency of points being used in the calculation, etc.) or how to get a p-value once the integral is calculated.

Any help on this would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You can't use estimated densities in a KS test (at least not using the usual distribution / tables). But why do you need to compare the KDE rather than the samples from which you computed it? Why wouldn't you do a KS test on the original samples?

Comment: Because our data is continuous and if I do KS on the original data I'd have to define some sort of bins which bring up the issues we are attempting to get rid of by using a KDE in the first place.

Comment: The Kolmogorov-Smirnov test is designed to work on continuous variables. Hmm. I wonder if we're using "continuous" in relation to different things. [But even if I had to have binned data, to compare two sets I still wouldn't smooth it before trying to compare distributions with KS, I'd adapt the test to the data, not screw around with the structure of it by smoothing (which makes testing it even more of a problem).] Can you explain what your original variables are, and what was done to the information at each stage, up to the calculation of KDEs?